# Record types as compile-time constant

Tags: typescript, types

A new-ish addition to TypeScript is the `as const` clause, which specifies objects and arrays as compile-time, readonly constant values, whose types are atomically specific.

```js
const x: {
  key: "value"
} as const
```

is represented by the type

```
readonly { "key": "value" }
```

This is a superb feature, allowing `const` object declarations which I can use for other types.
However when I need to declare an map of types as compile-time constants, which extends a `Record` type, it seems that the `as const` clause and the `Record` type have *opposite* effects.

```js
enum Enum {
  key1,
  key2,
}

const staticMap: Record<Enum, string> = {
  [Enum.key1]: "value1",
  [Enum.key2]: "value2"
} as const;
```

yields the type `Record<Enum, string>`, despite being marked as `const`.
Omitting the type gives the correct type annotation, however I lose the restriction to use members of `Enum` as keys to `staticMap`.

To be honest, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm wondering whether's some sort of halfway point, such that the following snippet fails:

```js
const x: <all values must be assignable to `string`> = {
  [Enum.key1]: "string",
  [Enum.key2]: 123
} as const
```

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify the type of a variable, that is it's final type, so as long as the expression on the right is assignable to it, everything is fine.

In this case you might want to remove the `as const` and specify the fact that the record is readonly:

```
enum Enum {
  key1,
  key2,
}

const staticMap: Readonly<Record<Enum, string>> = {
  [Enum.key1]: "value1",
  [Enum.key2]: "value2"
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQUoGtgE8CMAaF6WATPgL5JIDGA9iAM4AuUjAhgwJaUCyLADgFxQASsBYATWgBtMAHhE0ATmJlxIuZgwXsQAcwB8eqAF4oyVAG1VEAHQYcAXUEAiAG4tJYYNif4LV28SOUK7unkROSKQA3EA)

The version above does not fully emulate `as const`. If you want to preserve the value types as well you will need to use a generic function to capture the original value passed in for each property. This is closer to the behavior of `as const`:

```
enum Enum {
  key1,
  key2,
}

function makeRecord<T extends Record<Enum, V>, V extends string>(o: T): Readonly<T> {
  return o
}
const staticMap = makeRecord({
  [Enum.key1]: "value1",
  [Enum.key2]: "value2"
});


const x: typeof staticMap[Enum.key1] = "value2"; // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQUoGtgE8CMAaF6WATPgL5JIBmYIAxgC4CWA9iFBAIYYBKwtzAJwAmAHgAqUYAA96oIQGcovfsJFxIuKADUAfJq2SZcxfPoDGIAOY6AFMwBcUMQEpHvDkNYAbTOJ1RkVAFgejABNmYkcn4QUyhTDiZaAFkOAAcoAF52LmBlQSEbQKgAbXUIADoMHABdRwAiADcOLzBgbHr8VDL4KuI6qCaWtqJ6qOcAbgokGLipR3pMNOBmSnj6RMYU9J7IPtqswebW4FGppCA)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response, I do see one issue though: [Added a line which should fail](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQUoGtgE8CMAaF6WATPgL5JIDGA9iAM4AuUjAhgwJaUCyLADgFxQASsBYATWgBtMAHhE0ATmJlxIuZgwXsQAcwB8eqAF4oyVAG1VEAHQYcAXUEAiAG4tJYYNif4LV28SOUK7unkROSKQA3BQ09EwAHoIMmLzA1ABmGmycPLyW8AEOxsFuHsDhUUA), but doesn't.